# Janus gridEx support for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, janus, gridex

I was searching in the web to find out the version of Janus libraries I have (1.0.2500) will be supported by .NET 3.0 and after.

right now, we are using .NET 2.0 and we are in the process of upgrading the project to latest .NET , I am doing the step by step .NET improvement to make sure things are fine, the project builds fine and I can see the grid and work with grid functions (expand, etc) while project is executed. but in design mode, when I try to Edit grid Features I get the below error

system.notSupported.exception. The invoked member is not supported in a dynamically assembly

Does any one know what version of Janus is supported by .NET 3.0 and after?

appreciate a lot your help

Comment: You better contact Janus support at their website : http://www.janusys.com/ , They will help you.

Comment: thanks, posted the questions there, hopefully, there is a version we can have to accommodate this.

Comment: I think, I may have found it : http://www.componentsource.com/products/janus-gridex-net/index.html

Comment: Hi Guys, I have this problem, and I cant find the solution, please help